# user_list_map <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>: No speakable text present

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to create a route planner app and I'm getting the error user_list_map <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView>: No speakable text present' I don't understand what this error is telling more nor do I understand what I need to do for it.

Here is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">



    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:background="@color/white">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:id="@+id/user_list_recycler_view">

        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:id="@+id/map_container">

            <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/user_list_map"/>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Heres the Java code:

```
package com.example.destinationrouteplanner.ui;

import static com.example.destinationrouteplanner.Constants.MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.R;
import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.adapters.UserRecyclerAdapter;
import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.models.MarkerCluster;
import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.models.User;
import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.models.UserLocation;
import com.example.destinationrouteplanner.util.MyClusterManagerRenderer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class UserListFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback
{
    private static final String TAG = "UserListFragment";

    private RecyclerView mUserListRecyclerView;

    private MapView mMapView;

    private ArrayList<User> mUserList = new ArrayList<>();

    private UserRecyclerAdapter mUserRecyclerAdapter;
    private ArrayList<UserLocation> mUserLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private LatLngBounds mMapBoundary;
    private UserLocation mUserPosition;
    private ClusterManager mClusterManager;
    private MyClusterManagerRenderer mClusterManagerRenderer;
    private ArrayList<MarkerCluster> mClusterMarkers = new ArrayList<>();


    public static UserListFragment newInstance() {
        return new UserListFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mUserList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList(getString(R.string.intent_user_list));
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_list, container, false);
        mUserListRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_list_recycler_view);
        mMapView = view.findViewById(R.id.user_list_map);

        initUserListRecyclerView();
        initGoogleMap(savedInstanceState);

        return view;
    }

    private void initGoogleMap(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        // *** IMPORTANT ***
        // MapView requires that the Bundle you pass contain _ONLY_ MapView SDK
        // objects or sub-Bundles.
        Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);

        }

        mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);

        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private void initUserListRecyclerView() {
        mUserRecyclerAdapter = new UserRecyclerAdapter(mUserList);
        mUserListRecyclerView.setAdapter(mUserRecyclerAdapter);
        mUserListRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        Bundle mapViewBundle = outState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
        if (mapViewBundle == null) {
            mapViewBundle = new Bundle();
            outState.putBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY, mapViewBundle);
        }

        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(mapViewBundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap = map;
        addMapMarkers();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    private void addMapMarkers()
    {
        if (mGoogleMap !=null)
        {
            if(mClusterManager == null)
            {
                mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MarkerCluster>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), mGoogleMap);
            }
            if (mClusterManagerRenderer == null)
            {
                mClusterManagerRenderer = new MyClusterManagerRenderer(getActivity(), mGoogleMap, mClusterManager);
                mClusterManager.setRenderer(mClusterManagerRenderer);
            }
            for (UserLocation userLocation: mUserLocations)
            {
                Log.d(TAG, "AddMapMarkers: location: " + userLocation.getGeo_point().toString());
                try {
                    String snippet = "";
                    if (userLocation.getUser().getUser_id().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()))
                    {
                        snippet = "This is you";
                    }else {
                        snippet = "Determine route to " + userLocation.getUser().getUsername() + "?";
                    }
                    int avatar = R.drawable.speedvanimage; //Set the default avatar
                    try {
                        avatar = Integer.parseInt(userLocation.getUser().getAvatar());
                    }catch (NumberFormatException e)
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG, "addMapMarkers: no avatar for: " + userLocation.getUser().getUsername() + ", setting default");
                    }
                    MarkerCluster newMarkerCluster = new MarkerCluster(new LatLng(userLocation.getGeo_point().getLatitude(), userLocation.getGeo_point().getLongitude()),userLocation.getUser().getUsername(), snippet, avatar, userLocation.getUser());
                    mClusterManager.addItem(newMarkerCluster);
                    mClusterMarkers.add(newMarkerCluster);
                }catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, "addMapMarkers: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            mClusterManager.cluster();
            setCameraView();
        }
    }
    private void setCameraView()
    {
        double bottomBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLatitude() - .1;
        double leftBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLongitude() - .1;
        double topBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLatitude() - .1;
        double rightBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLongitude() - .1;
    }
}
```

Still not sure why this error is coming up weird because it shouldn't be really

Comment: Can you add the code to the class holding this layout please ?

Answer (score 0):

**To fix this error, you can try the following:**

**(1)** Make sure that the map view was created with the android:speakable="true" attribute.

**(2)** If the map view was created with the android:speakable="true" attribute, but the speakable text was removed, you can add it back by calling the setOnMapClickListener() method on the map view and passing in an OnMapClickListener that implements the onMapClick() method. The onMapClick() method should return the speakable text for the clicked location.
Here is an example of how to create a map view with speakable text:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
 android:id="@+id/mapView"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:speakable="true" />
```